# Binding Properties of a Converter Inside a Style for CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, custom-controls, converters

I have a converter that maps a percentage into a range. It has two dependency properties for storing the start and end of the range. Below is an example of it's declaration:

```
<local:PercentToRangeConverter RangeStart="50" RangeEnd="200" />
```

I'm using the converter in a style for a CustomControl's `Width` where the `MinWidth` and the `MaxWidth` is bound to the `RangeStart` and the `RangeEnd` of the converter. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've already made sure that the converter itself is working by manually setting the values of the `RangeStart` and the `RangeEnd` with an arbitrary number.

---

I've done two ways for binding the properties of the CustomControl to the converters:

1. **Declare the converter inside the Style.Resources, bind the properties inside there, then use the converter as a static resource.**

> ```
> <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
>     <Style.Resources>
>           <local:PercentToRangeConverter x:Key="PercentToRangeConverter"
>               RangeStart="{Binding MinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}"
>               RangeEnd="{Binding MaxWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" />
>     </Style.Resources>
>     . . .
> ```

2. **Declare the converter inside the converter property of a Binding tag inside the setter's value**

> ```
>     . . .
>     <Setter Property="Width">
>         <Setter.Value>
>             <Binding Path="Percent" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
>                 <Binding.Converter>
>                     <local:PercentToRangeConverter
>                         RangeStart="{Binding MinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}"
>                         RangeEnd="{Binding MaxWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" />
>                 </Binding.Converter>
>             </Binding>
>         </Setter.Value>
>     </Setter>
>     . . . 
> </Style>
> ```

Again, these work when I manually set the value. So I think `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` is incorrect for the binding but I can't think of anything else so that I can bind the CustomControl's `Width`. I also think that both methods don't have the same proper way for setting the source considering that the way the converter is declared is different for both methods. Either way, I just want to succesfully bind the `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` to the converter.

P.S. Is "declare" even the proper term for that?

---

**EDIT:** Here's the code for the Converter as requested.

```
public class PercentToRangeConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public double RangeStart
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RangeStartProperty);
        set => SetValue(RangeStartProperty, value);
    }

    protected static readonly DependencyProperty RangeStartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RangeStart", typeof(double), typeof(PercentToRangeConverter), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double RangeEnd
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RangeEndProperty);
        set => SetValue(RangeEndProperty, value);
    }

    protected static readonly DependencyProperty RangeEndProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RangeEnd", typeof(double), typeof(PercentToRangeConverter), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * (RangeEnd - RangeStart) + RangeStart;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT (1):** Forgot to add, I'm actually searching for answers other than `MultiBinding`. The reason is I'm animating the `Percent` value. I thought that `MultiBinding` might affect the performance.

Comment: You forgot to post the defintion of the converter. Even if it's a `DependencyObject` it is not added to the visual tree and this means that you cannot bind to a property of a visual ancestor.

Comment: If `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` are plain CLR properties, then they can't be Biding targets.

Comment: @sthotakura I just posted the code for the converter, they are dependency properties

Comment: @mm8 So I can't use the `RelativeSource` right? How can I set the `Source` of the Binding then?

Comment: You can use multi-value converter or just pass values into view model and calculate result there.

Comment: @Sinatr Oh sorry, I forgot to add in the post that I'm searching for answers other than MultiBinding

Comment: It seems you are trying to layout the control. It may be a better idea to study existing [containers](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/) or you can easily make own customer container and even use custom attached properties to define parameters for it (see [tutorial](https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/10/08/1175-custom-panel-part-vii/)).

Comment: You can implement a `MarkupExtension` which handles this for you. But this solution is far more complex than using a simple `MultiBinding` - that's what a `MultiBinding` is for. Just turn your converter into a `IMultiValueConverter` and you are done.

Comment: @BionicCode But how about perforamnce with regards to by last edit?

Comment: There shouldn't be any significant difference. The point is, you have at least three bindings: `MinWidth`, `MaxWidth` and `Percent`. It doesn't matter if these bindings are spread throughout your code or consolidated into a `MultiBinding` object. Actually you just bypass the extra properties of the converter.

Comment: I think the `MultiBinding` (or `MultiBindingExpression`) tracks each binding and caches their values to prevent the execution of a binding where the property has not changed.

Comment: Why would a `MultiBinding` affect the performance more than binding to the same properties using two individual dependency properties?

Comment: Hmm, will use MultiBinding as the solution for now. But I'll still look forward for a solution for the question. Thanks!